# System.Threading.Thread replacement in UWP / Windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, uwp

In UWP, how can I access the thread object? I want to change the name of the main thread and additional thread that I will manage.

I also want to check if the current thread is the main thread afterwards.

I'm targeting to windows 10 mobile. The following code example works for desktop, but not for phone (getting 'System.DllNotFoundException'):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Tasks instead of threads. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

As about renaming of threads, can you tell me why do you need to rename main thread and other threads!?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I've already seen tasks prior to asking this question. My app has a constant worker thread. From what I've read, tasks are intended for single asynchronous operations. Is there really no way of working with threads?

Comment: Tasks are not for only single async ops. You can use task as threads. Actually underneath Task is the Thread. So just try to switch from threads and use tasks. You can start one task that later can starts other tasks. You do not need to wait till tasks ends, just fire it up and forget, but provide some mechanism for task to finish gracefully. For this you can use Task Cancellation  Token.

Comment: Ray, look at this blog:
http://blog.slaks.net/2013-10-11/threads-vs-tasks/

It states there: "Since tasks still run on the ThreadPool, they should not be used for long-running operations, since they can still fill up the thread pool and block new work. Instead, Task provides a LongRunning option, which will tell the TaskScheduler to spin up a new thread rather than running on the ThreadPool."

Eventually, I need a thread that will stay alive through the app's lifecycle. Perhaps creating the task with LongRunning option is the way to go...

Comment: You misunderstood. I'm not refusing to use them. Thanks for the answer, I'm inspecting this solution combined with what I suggested.

Comment: I've ended up using long running task, as I stated before. Thanks!

Comment: How did you prevent task switches when using await? Everytime i use `await Task.Delay` it switches.

Comment: Benni, not sure I understand the question or it's relevance to the subject

Answer (score 2):

You should try System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId (yes, you can get only current thread id)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

We've blogged about this at length (as we feel this is an unwelcome start of the fragmentation of .NET Standard) and have published an open source `System.Threading.Thread` implementation for UWP/UAP 10, [available on GitHub](https://github.com/neosmart/TaskThreads) and [via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskThread/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately that one doesn't include ThreadPool (used DedicatedThreadPool with some small changes instead)

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, you should look into using the classes from the [Windows.System.Threading namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.threading). However, you will notice there is a thread pool, but no direct equivalent of the Thread class.

Remember that there are reasons why UWP does not allow you to just create a thread and leave it running for ever. That would make it too easy to drain the battery, but it would also get in the way of app suspension.

UWP has many mechanisms that allow you to do the kinds of things that on other platforms might be solved by using a dedicated thread. Maybe if you told us why you think you need a thread, we can help you in solving your actual problem?